# Antenna Parallel to High Voltage Line Has AC Current - Is It Acting as an Inductor?

Tags: rf, antenna, inductor

I'm attempting to use one of the roofline gutters on my house as a "longwire" antenna.  The center conductor of my coax cable connects to the gutter, the shield conductor to a grounding rod.  The gutter is near the same height, parallel to, and roughly fifty feet from a high voltage transmission line.  When I was putting a connector on the transmitter side of the cable, I was suprized to receive small shocks, like static electricity.  My multimeter shows fluctuating voltage when I measure between the two cable conductors, with a peak around 65 VAC.  Is it possible that my gutter is within the electromagnetic field of the power line and is acting as an inductor?  If so, any suggestions on how to minimize the effect to still use it as an antenna?

Comment: If it is an option, use another side of the house, where the gutter is at right angles to the overhead power lines. The coax is quite possibly picking up induced voltage from the HT wires above, if they are approximately parallel.

Comment: 65 VAC? I thought harvesting or "stealing" power from transmission lines was debunked because of how little power can actually be inductively generated, without extreme proximity. At 65 VAC I would be suspicious that it's not the transmission lines but something else.

Comment: @JYelton High voltage, but probably minuscule available current: If the available current (and thus power) had been significant, Dave might not have been posting questions right now :-) I've been left with aching shoulder sockets for a while after a decent-sized 50 Volt AC shock.

Comment: There is a 20 foot run of parallel coax at ground level; I hadn't considered the coax might be part of the issue.  Could I filter the coax with a choke or bead?  I agree with very low current. I also tested with a 4 Watt 120 Volt night-light bulb. If I understand Power Law correctly, the bulb draws .03 Amp at 120 Volts. If there was current, I should have got a little light from the bulb even at half voltage, but not a flicker. Since I doubt I will risk connecting this "antenna" to my radio, I jokingly told my wife I could build a simple rectifier and turn it into a battery trickle charger.

Answer (score 1):

It's a capacitor, not an inductor. You have something like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0Ng47.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Remember, any two conductors can make a capacitor. Your gutter has some capacitance to ground (C2), and some to the HV line (C1). The two make a [capacitive voltage divider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider#Capacitive_divider), and if the gutter isn't otherwise connected to something else providing a lower impedance to 60 Hz than those capacitors, you will see some voltage, relative to ground, on your gutter.

Comment: Thanks Phil. Not completely sure I agree with your assessment, but being fairly new to application of electrical fields and how they work, I won't argue with your explanation. My main benefit is that you and the other respondants validate my theory that I'm getting voltage from the transmission line that is parallel to my setup. I'm currently looking at an alternative to using the gutter to transmit my RF signals. Thanks to you and the others who responded to this question; you gave me the answers I was looking for.

Comment: @Dave it never hurts to wait a bit to see if anyone else will answer before accepting. Once you accept, some people won't read the question. If you want to unaccept, my feelings won't be hurt. Also, if you tell me why you disagree, I'll see if either I can clarify, or see where I was wrong.